# "Seemed connected" vs "Seemed to be connected."

Tags: grammar

Example:

> From this angle the bridge looked just like a garden path—due to the
>   grass and flowers growing along it and that seemed (to be) connected
>   to the land ahead.

Should I use to be here? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes. Because that is idiomatic English.

Comment: Tangential point: "Due to" is used very frequently in this way but is regarded as substandard. "Because of" is preferred. With regard to your question "seemed connected" is also perfectly acceptable, and some might say preferable.

Comment: @TimRomano Thanks for the tip. Why is *due to* substandard?

Comment: http://linguistech.ca/Tips+and+Tricks+-+Because+of+vs.+Due+to

Comment: It is considered substandard by people who love to dictate how others should talk or write. Or by people anxious to protect the English language from 'deteriorating.' There are probably other reasons too. But to label a form as substandard is a value judgment.

Answer (score 1):

......that seemed (to be) connected to the land ahead. I think "to be" is optional here. You can use or omit it, it makes no difference in meaning.